# How do I get Cypress just to process the visible element?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to use this one element:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy-component=single-picker-search] input').type('Live');
```

When I run it, it tells me there are more than 1 of them, so it can't do it.

I tried adding { force: true } - that made no difference.

I tried looking at each element, but this fails if the element is not visible:

```js
cy.get(singlePickerSearch).each(($el) => {
  cy.wrap($el).type('Live' + '{enter}');
});
```

How do I make it just type where the element is visible? I do not want it to fail on this.

Comment: Do you know which of input is visible during this test (e.g. first/third/last)?

Comment: No, I can only see only search text.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Got it. You can use pseudo selector `:visible` so you will be able to do

```
cy.get('[data-cy-component=single-picker-search] input:visible').type(...)
```

or in case if more than one is visible select first visible input

```
cy.get('[data-cy-component=single-picker-search] input:visible').first().type(...)
```

Answer (score 55):

This didn't work for me on a button I was trying to get:

`cy.get('[data-cy-component=single-picker-search] button:visible')`

This is what ended up working for me:

`cy.get('[data-cy-component=single-picker-search]').filter(':visible')`

Comment: That filter should be in quotes, shouldn't it? Like this: .filter(':visible')

Comment: this worked for me too, the first one did not work (updated nov 2021)

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/filter